Angular build fails when deployed
Why don't I see any local errors when using ng build? When I do ng build --configuration=qa locally I don't see any error logs, only warnings:

But when it's deployed on Azure I see errors:
    node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=qa --output-path=...
    Application bundle generation failed. [21.677 seconds]

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "moment"

    node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter/fesm2022/material-moment-adapter.mjs:4:31:
      4 │ import * as _rollupMoment from 'moment';

 [ERROR] TS2307: Cannot find module '@arcgis/core/Graphic' or its corresponding type declarations. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/_features/ems/services/esri-map.service.ts:3:20:
      3 │ import Graphic from '@arcgis/core/Graphic';


Are moment and @arcgis/core/Graphic in your dependencies section in your package.json? It sounds like locally you might either have those in devDependencies or installed globally. Try replicating your pipeline locally by blowing away node_modules and running npm ci --production prior to building.
